# Is `c` or `t` the positive line of a differential pair?

Tags: identification, differential, differential-amplifier

I'm looking at the W66CP2NQUAFJ from Winbond. It has a couple of pins, namely `CK_t_A` and `CK_c_A`. In the datasheet, it says that these are differential pairs, but nowhere does it state which is the positive/negative line.

Does anyone know which is which?

Comment: Memory is standardized so its probably assumed you already know from the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"t" stands for "true"; this is the positive (non-inverted) input.

"c" stands for "complement"; this is the negative (inverted) input.

Answer (score 1):

From [Winbonn W66BP6NB / W66CP2NQ 2Gb / 4Gb LPDDR4](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/W66BP6NB_W66CP2NQ_WFBGA200_datasheet_A01-001_20200623.pdf) data sheet page 5.

> Clock: **CK_t** and **CK_c** are differential clock inputs. All address, command, and control input signals are sampled on the crossing of the **positive edge of CK_t** and the **negative edge of CK_c**. AC timings for CA parameters are referenced to CK. Each channel (A & B) has its own clock pair.

Even if it was not stated there, it is clearly seen from the timing diagrams.  From page 86:

[image]

From Page 215:

> 8.3.2.5 Differential Input Cross Point Voltage
> The cross point voltage of differential input signals (CK_t, CK_c) must meet the requirements in Table 96.

> The differential input cross point voltage VIX is measured from the actual cross point of **true** and **complement** signals to the mid level.

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, very detailed for the specific part. But, I would rather accept @Jonathan S.'s answer, as it is more generic for memory and just EE in general.